# Is it possible to deal with mxarray at CUDA kernel code?

Tags: matlab, cuda, mex

I try to pass all the mxArray, as its type, to kernel code of CUDA. Is it logical and possible to process it on kernel with mxArray type or converting to the ordinary C array is better approach? For short what is the best way to process matlab data on CUDA kernel ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't operate on `mxArray`s. It is best if you extract the C pointer and pass them to the kernel.

Comment: @Erogol Yes, use `mxGetPr` or equivalent functions to get C pointers to `mxArray`. You can copy data from these pointers to the gpus and use CUDA code.